selenium: can't find element on webpage
I'm extracting the user reviews from imdb with Selenium but when I try extracting the rating from each review, I receive this error:

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".rating-other-user-rating span"}

The html path of the element is:
<div>
    <div class="inline-rating">
        <div class="ipl-ratings-bar">
            <span class="rating-other-user-rating">
                <svg class="ipl-icon ipl-star-icon  " xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#000000" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24">
                    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
                    <path d="M12 17.27L18.18 21l-1.64-7.03L22 9.24l-7.19-.61L12 2 9.19 8.63 2 9.24l5.46 4.73L5.82 21z"></path>
                    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
                </svg>
                <span>4</span>
                <span class="point-scale">/10</span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="/review/rw3316476/?ref_=tt_urv" class="title"> The Most Over-Rated Show I Have Ever Seen</a>
</div>

The code I tried to use is
service = Service(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
url = 'https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0903747/reviews?ref_=tt_urv'
driver.get(url)
review_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'review-container')

#I tried searching the rating (in this case 4) with all the following codes, but I receive the error
rating = review_element.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'inline-rating')
rating = review_element.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'ipl-ratings-bar')
rating = review_element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.rating-other-user-rating span')
rating = review_element.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'rating-other-user-rating')

It's odd because I managed to pick the title, the text, the date and the user name without problems.

The problem is that one of the review about halfway down the page does not have a rating. So when you're looping through all of the review-containers, when one of them doesn't have a rating you get a NoSuchElementException.
I fixed up the code and added a try-except to handle the missing rating.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0903747/reviews?ref_=tt_urv'
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
review_elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'review-container')))
for review_element in review_elements:
    try:
        rating = review_element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.rating-other-user-rating')
        print(rating.text)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        # no rating, ignore
        pass

It outputs
10/10
10/10
10/10
10/10
10/10
10/10
10/10
10/10
10/10
10/10
7/10
5/10
10/10
10/10
10/10
10/10
10/10
10/10
10/10
10/10
6/10
5/10
10/10
10/10

